# how to get value of element with dynamically created id

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
$(".cbtn").click(function(e) {
    alert("here");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var comment = $('input[id$=id]').val();     
    alert("hay" + id);
    alert(comment);

    $.post("comments.php", {
        id: id, 
        comment: comment
    })
});
});
```

The `id` of `cbtn` and the text field is created dynamically like this:

```
<input type="text" class="enter_comment  value="comments" id="comm<?php echo $row['p_id'];?>"/>
<input type="button" value="enter" class="cbtn" id="<?php echo $row['p_id'];>">
```

When `cbtn` is clicked, I want to get the `id` of text field that ends with the same id as `cbtn`. But it is returning `undefined` instead.

Comment: `$('input[id$="'+'id+'"]').val();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to concatenate the `id` variable in the selector, like this:

```
$(".cbtn").click(function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    var comment = $('input[id$=' + id + ']').val();         
    $.post("comments.php", {
        id: id, 
        comment: comment
    })
});
```

Alternatively, as the `id` of the text field is the same as the checkbox, but with `comm` prepended, you could select it by `id` directly, which would be quicker:

```
var comment = $('#comm' + id).val();
```

Or, if the text field is always the element preceding the checkbox, you could negate the need to select by `id` completely and use the `prev()` method:

```
$(".cbtn").click(function(e) {
    $.post("comments.php", {
        id: this.id, 
        comment: $(this).prev().val()
    })
});
```

Comment: It should match as the `$=` selector is 'attribute ends with'

Comment: Yeah. Yeesh. I really need to get my head together today. But I'd definitely go with your `$('#comm' + id).val()` or if I'm paranoid about things that might need escaping, `$('[id="comm' + id + '"]').val()`.

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Sounds like you enjoyed Christmas ;) I agree, either of the latter two is the better solution.

Comment: @puffles no problem, glad to help.